# Convert string to uniqueidentifier in VBScript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, uniqueidentifier

I have a script that runs a stored procedure in my SQL server database, the problem is the stored procedure takes a uniqueidentifier parameter.  I have a function that grabs a session id from the database (which is an nvarchar), so VBScript makes it a string and I need to convert it to pass it to the stored procedure.

```
Function GetOpenSession
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=" & Source
    rs.CursorLocation = 3
    rs.Open "SELECT top 1 OpenSession FROM OpenSessions with (nolock)" , conn, 3, 3
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Connection"
    Else
        GetOpenSession = rs.Fields(0).Value
    End If
End Function
```

I get "Invalid character value for cast specification" when I try to execute the stored procedure.

```
    set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@ActiveSession",72,1,,GetOpenSession)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
```

I can't change anything in the database, so I need a way to overcome this in my script.

Comment: How do you know that "SELECT top 1 OpenSession FROM OpenSessions with (nolock)" will give you the active session?  You're just picking the first OpenSession value regardless of which session it represents.

Comment: The only sessions stored in this table are active sessions, so it does not matter which one I use.

Comment: Hmmm... ok, but it sounds like a strange architecture if you don't care *which* active session ID you are passing to the proc.

Comment: The application does care it only uses it's own session, I'm testing the application so I don't care what session I use just that there is an open session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the data type of the SELECT OpenSession, you may be able to cast/convert it in the query and VBScript may possibly keep the data type as a GUID:

```
SELECT top 1 CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, OpenSession)
FROM OpenSessions with (nolock)
```

When you use `GetOpenSession` or `rs.Fields(0).Value`, hopefully VBScript will keep it as a GUID.

The other possibility seems to be a Win32 API using [`CoCreateGuid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688568.aspx) and [`StringFromGUID2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683893.aspx). An example is found [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/tip078.shtml), but it requires external Win32 functions and a Type for GUID.

Comment: Genius! I can't believe I didn't think of CONVERT.

Answer (score 5):

I believe VBScript expects GUIDs to be brace terminated. 
Is your Session id of the same format as the following {D6CA6263-E8E1-41C1-AEA6-040EA89BF030}

Comment: No and it is also stored in the database as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I usually change the parameter type of the stored procedure to varchar(38).

SQL Server makes a better job of coercing the string to a GUID when needed.

Comment: I don't control the database, and can't change anything in it.  I'm just a tester, and developers don't like changing things just to help us.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of GetOpenSession after you have assigned it?  Which datatype?  It sounds like it is not compatible with type 72 (GUID), which you are stating in the CreateParameter call.

Comment: It is a string.  But if I try to create the parameter with type 8 (String) I get "Error converting data type nchar to uniqueidentifier."

Answer (score 0):

You could forget about using ADO Commands altogether and just execute the stored procedure using plain SQL.

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open "EXEC usp_MySP '" & GetOpenSession & "'", cnn
```

Obviously it's terrible to build SQL commands like this, but it's just for a test, after all...

Comment: Just a test?! It will be a routine that is added to a suite of tests used for testing applications. Just like developers write and maintain millions of lines of code to make the application work, testers sometimes do the same to make sure the app works correctly.  So no it's not just a test.